# How to add a TextView to a settings bundle in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

Is there any any way to add a TextView to application settings in Iphone. According to Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html), I can only find TextField, but not TextView. I have tried several key values like **PSTextViewSpecifier**, but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings bundle does not support a TextView.

Comment: Thanks. But how the signature in mail application works?If I am not wrong, it is a TextView inside a Child pane.

Comment: One possibility is that it uses Undocumented Apple APIs.  More likely is the Settings.app has the "Mail, Contacts, Calendars"  preference list hardcoded as it includes things like "Import SIM Contacts", a "settings" item that executes code -- also an impossible feat for mere mortal Settings.bundles.

Comment: Thanks. Actually textfield is still ok for my need, but I was looking for something more.