# How to add "Signature option" in Settings.bundle using xcode6.1?

Tags: ios7, xcode6, settings.bundle

I want to add "Signature option" in Settings.bundle like below screenshot,

[image]

where the **Signature: Sent from my iPhone is an editable textview** like below screenshot,

[image]

When I select `Type - Multi Value` in `Settings.bundle` file, it gives option for adding multiple values.

How to achieve this? I am using Xcode6.1

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution by adding `Type - Child Pane` in `Root.plist` and adding below code in new `Signature.plist` for Signature

[image]

But it displays only **Signature** instead of **Signature: Sent from my iPhone** like below screenshot,

[image]

and it even doensn't display the default text in textfield (The textfield is empty), and in the options for `Type` there is no `TextView`. Only I can add TextField, then how to make it **multiline like TextView**?

I found one answer saying [The settings bundle does not support a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952161/how-to-add-a-textview-to-a-settings-bundle-in-iphone). Can't we add a Textview?